# Update em ano sem alterar o Mês, dia e hora

Tags: sql, oracle, data, sql-update

Estou tentando fazer um script para alterar o ano de um registro de uma tabela onde o campo dta_encerramento tem a data no formato de 25/08/2091 13:06:00 em banco de dados Oracle.

Preciso alterar o ano 2091.

Quando executo o script abaixo ele altera o ano porem altera também o dia, mês e deixa sem a hora.

```
UPDATE tabela_aa SET dta_encerramento = TO_DATE('2018', 'YYYY') where dta_encerramento between '28-07-2017' and '29-08-2017';
```

Preciso alterar registro de vários dias diferentes para o mesmo ano.

Tem alguma forma de fazer com que isso não ocorra e consiga altera somente o ano da data que está no registro da tabela?

Comment: Talvez adicionar / subtrair os meses necessários. Por exemplo: somar 1 ano seria a mesma coisa que `somar 12 meses`, assim, não afetaria o restante da data.

Comment: Talvez estes links possam ajudar:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48575/update-year-alone-in-date-oracle-11g/48604

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=changing-a-year-within-a-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converta para `char` buscando o dia e mês, depois adicione o ano e converta pra `date` novamente:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(dta_encerramento ,'dd/mm') || '/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Para incluir a hora junto, utilize esse:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(dta_encerramento ,'ddmmhh24miss') || '2018','ddmmhh24missRRRR')
```

Comment: testei com esse formato troca o ano, mas apaga a hora do campo. Preciso que fique com a data e hora

Comment: TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(dta_encerramento ,'dd/mm hh24miss') || '/2018','dd/mm/yyyy  hh24miss')

Comment: Inclui na resposta um opção para fazer com a hora junto. O importante é você entender o que está fazendo...

Comment: Consegui resolver usei o 

UPDATE tabela_aa SET dta_encerramento = dta_encerramento - INTERVAL '71' YEAR WHERE dta_encerramento between '01-01-2091' and '29-12-2091';

Obrigado a todos

Answer (score -1):

Cara quem deve poder lhe ajudar é a função replace.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm

Comment: Este tipo de resposta ficaria melhor se estivesse posicionada no lugar apropriado de comentário.